# I am Unable to Post Xml to Linkedin Share API

Tags: delphi, linkedin-api, indy

I am using Delphi 2010, with Indy 10.5.8(svn version) and oAuth.pas from chuckbeasley. I am able to collect token with app key and App secret, authorize token with a web page and Access the final token. Now I have to post a status with Linkedin’s Share API.  I am getting a unauthorized response.
My request and responses are giving bellow.
Request,

```
    POST /v1/people/~/shares HTTP/1.0
Content-Encoding: utf-8
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=us-ascii
Content-Length: 999
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xxx",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1340438599",oauth_nonce="BB4C78E0A6EB452BEE0FAA2C3F921FC4",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_token="xxx",oauth_signature="Pz8%2FPz8%2FPz9ePzkxPyc%2FDD82Pz8%3D"
Host: api.linkedin.com
Accept: text/html, */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)

%3C%3Fxml+version=%25221.0%2522%2520encoding%253D%2522UTF-8%2522%253F%253E%253Cshare%253E%253Ccomment%253E83%2525%2520of%2520employers%2520will%2520use%2520social%2520media%2520to%2520hire%253A%252078%2525%2520LinkedIn%252C%252055%2525%2520Facebook%252C%252045%2525%2520Twitter%2520%255BSF%2520Biz%2520Times%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Fbit.ly%252FcCpeOD%253C%252Fcomment%253E%253Ccontent%253E%253Ctitle%253ESurvey%253A%2520Social%2520networks%2520top%2520hiring%2520tool%2520-%2520San%2520Francisco%2520Business%2520Times%253C%252Ftitle%253E%253Csubmitted-url%253Ehttp%253A%252F%252Fsanfrancisco.bizjournals.com%252Fsanfrancisco%252Fstories%252F2010%252F06%252F28%252Fdaily34.html%253C%252Fsubmitted-url%253E%253Csubmitted-image-url%253Ehttp%253A%252F%252Fimages.bizjournals.com%252Ftravel%252Fcityscapes%252Fthumbs%252Fsm_sanfrancisco.jpg%253C%252Fsubmitted-image-url%253E%253C%252Fcontent%253E%253Cvisibility%253E%253Ccode%253Eanyone%253C%252Fcode%253E%253C%252Fvisibility%253E%253C%252Fshare%253E
```

Response,

```
    HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
x-li-request-id: K14SWRPEPL
Date: Sat, 23 Jun 2012 08:07:17 GMT
Vary: *
x-li-format: xml
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 341
Connection: keep-alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error>
  <status>401</status>
  <timestamp>1340438838344</timestamp>
  <request-id>K14SWRPEPL</request-id>
  <error-code>0</error-code>
  <message>[unauthorized]. OAU:xxx|nnnnn|*01|*01:1340438599:Pz8/Pz8/Pz9ePzkxPyc/DD82Pz8=</message>
</error>
```

Please help.

Regards,

Vijesh Nair

Comment: Hi Vijesh, a few things about your post. There's no question, what is *oAuth.pas from chuckbeasley* where we can download it, what is *post a status with Linkedin's Share API* a link to the API reference would be useful, what is the code you used ? Could you format your request in a proper XML, not as bunch of encoded chars ? Just one sidenote about charset, it seems you are sending your request with the `Content-Type: text/xml; charset=us-ascii` but I think you should have `Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8`.

Comment: I don't think it's "Delphi" that cannot post XML, as the title suggests ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, you can download oAuth.pas , [link](http://chuckbeasley.wordpress.com/2009/04/29/using-oauth-for-delphi/).    Share API reference is at [link] (http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-api).

Comment: @Wouter, Delphi can Post the XML. I am not able to understand, whats happening with the LinkedIn API.

Comment: Also, I am able to GET the current status. When I am trying to post,I am getting the above error.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment on the content of your `Authentication` header, but the rest of your HTTP request is definately not correct, which tells me that you are not using the `TIdHTTP.Post()` method correctly.  In particular, the XML has been url-encoded TWICE (only one of which would have been Indy's doing), and the `Content-Encoding` header is wrong.

I suspect that you are making the common newbie mistake of posting the XML using the `TStrings` overloaded version of `TIdHTTP.Post()`, and also pre-encoding the XML beforehand.  Neither of those will work.  You must use the `TStream` overloaded version instead, and do not pre-encode the XML at all.

The correct request should look more like this:

```
POST /v1/people/~/shares HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 571
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xxx",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1340438599",oauth_nonce="BB4C78E0A6EB452BEE0FAA2C3F921FC4",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_token="xxx",oauth_signature="Pz8%2FPz8%2FPz9ePzkxPyc%2FDD82Pz8%3D"
Host: api.linkedin.com
Accept: text/html, */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><share><comment>83% of employers will use social media to hire: 78% LinkedIn, 55% Facebook, 45% Twitter [SF Biz Times] http://bit.ly/cCpeOD</comment><content><title>Survey: Social networks top hiring tool - San Francisco Business Times</title><submitted-url>http://sanfrancisco.bizjournals.com/sanfrancisco/stories/2010/06/28/daily34.html</submitted-url><submitted-image-url>http://images.bizjournals.com/travel/cityscapes/thumbs/sm_sanfrancisco.jpg</submitted-image-url></content><visibility><code>anyone</code></visibility></share>
```

The code to produce that request should look something like this:

```
var
  PostData: TMemoryStream;
begin
  PostData := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    WriteStringToStream(PostData, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><share><comment>83% of employers will use social media to hire: 78% LinkedIn, 55% Facebook, 45% Twitter [SF Biz Times] http://bit.ly/cCpeOD</comment><content><title>Survey: Social networks top hiring tool - San Francisco Business Times</title><submitted-url>http://sanfrancisco.bizjournals.com/sanfrancisco/stories/2010/06/28/daily34.html</submitted-url><submitted-image-url>http://images.bizjournals.com/travel/cityscapes/thumbs/sm_sanfrancisco.jpg</submitted-image-url></content><visibility><code>anyone</code></visibility></share>', IndyUTF8Encoding);
    PostData.Position := 0;
    IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'text/xml';
    IdHTTP1.Request.Charset := 'utf-8';
    IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xxx",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1340438599",oauth_nonce="BB4C78E0A6EB452BEE0FAA2C3F921FC4",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_token="xxx",oauth_signature="Pz8%2FPz8%2FPz9ePzkxPyc%2FDD82Pz8%3D"';
    IdHTTP1.Post('http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares', PostData);
  finally
    PostData.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy for the comments and code. I made the change by adding idGlobal to uses class and adding the above code. I am getting the following Request,

Comment: [code] (POST /v1/people/~/shares HTTP/1.0
Content-Encoding: utf-8
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 571
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xxx",
 oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1340696206",oauth_nonce="E4359C3F45651BDE6671DC7BA5CBE9C4",oauth_version="1.0",
 oauth_token="xxx",oauth_signature="xxxx"
Host: api.linkedin.com
Accept: text/html, */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><share><comment>83% of employers will use social media to hire: 78% LinkedIn, 55% Facebook, 45% Twitter [SF Biz Times] http://bit.ly/cCpeOD</comment><content><title>Survey: Social networks top hiring tool - San Francisco Business Times</title><submitted-url>http://sanfrancisco.bizjournals.com/sanfrancisco/stories/2010/06/28/daily34.html</submitted-url><submitted-image-url>http://images.bizjournals.com/travel/cityscapes/thumbs/sm_sanfrancisco.jpg</submitted-image-url></content><visibility><code>anyone</code></visibility></share>
)

Comment: and Response is Almost same as my problem 

[code] (HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
x-li-request-id: 2F60JRT6NM
Date: Tue, 26 Jun 2012 07:40:48 GMT
Vary: *
x-li-format: xml
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 341
Connection: keep-alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error>
  <status>401</status>
  <timestamp>1340696449596</timestamp>
  <request-id>2F60JRT6NM</request-id>
  <error-code>0</error-code>
  <message>[unauthorized]. OAU:xxx|xxx|*01|*01:1340696206:xxxx/xx</message>
</error>

)

Comment: Sorry for adding in different comments, that was because of the limit of characters in stackoverflow.

Comment: Your `Content-Encoding` header is still wrong. UTF-8 is not a valid `Content-Encoding` value. You need to remove that. Aside from that, the rest looks ok, so the problem has to be in content of the `Authentication` header, which is outside the scope of Indy. Look for bugs in your oAuth-related code.

Comment: Thanks Remy for the Quick Response, I will check now and will come back to you.

Comment: HI Remy, I am so sorry to inform you that, not worked. I removed the content Encoding from the idhttp.request. still giving the same error.

Comment: Like I said, with everything else fixed, something in your `Authentication` header has to be wrong, since the server is complaining about authentication failure. So you need to step through the oAuth code and make sure everything is being calculated and generated correctly. That has nothing to do with Indy.

Comment: Thanks Remy for the comment. I have tested the Auth details by gathering the current status of the user. I got that successfully.  so I don't think there is any error in authentication.

Comment: It has to be in the oAuth data, because there is nothing else authentication-related in the POST data.